# Android - Layout behavior attribute causing the FrameLayout in CoordinatorLayout not matching parent

Tags: android, android-layout

My activity contains 2 `Toolbar`s at the top of screen, and I'm using a `CoordinatorLayout` to make the top one exit/enter the screen on scroll of a `RecyclerView`, and the other `Toolbar` will always follow it but not exiting the screen.

Another layout containing the `RecyclerView` forementioned is added into a `FrameLayout` container dynamically. The layout is from another package so I must add `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to the `FrameLayout` container to work with the `CoordinatorLayout`. And it works fine with no problem.

However, when I added another layout to the `FrameLayout`(a centered `ProgressBar` for example) instead of the `RecyclerView` , the bug showed. The `FrameLayout`, which `match_parent`, did not fill the screen, and its height was the same as `ProgressBar`.

After I deleted the line `app:layout_behavior...`, the `FrameLayout` succeeded to fill the screen. But at runtime when i want to add a `RecyclerView`, part of its 1st item is blocked by the `Toolbar`, because of the lack of `app:layout_behavior...` attribute.

**In a word**, if I add a `app:layout_behavior..` attribute to the `FrameLayout` which `match_parent`, the `RecyclerView` in it shows correctly but the `FrameLayout` only `wrap_content` in height; if not, it `match_parent` while the `RecyclerView` is blocked by the 2nd `Toolbar`.

Note that I can't add this attribute to `RecyclerView` directly, which is in another package.(but i can get the reference of it at runtime)

Below is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"

            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            style="@style/Toolbar"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/subToolbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:theme="@style/Toolbar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

UPDATE: I have solved the problem by adding an invisible `new View(this)` object , which fills the screen by default, to the `FrameLayout` at runtime before the `ProgressBar` is added.  But I still don't know why the bug occurs. And I think this solution is a hack.